# How to stop c# program auto selecting Windows Form Radio Button on launch

Tags: c#, forms, radio-button, label

I am a beginner so just bare with me.

For one of the papers, I am studying I have been tasked with making a prototype for a Gym Membership form and then making it useable. It has been a struggle so far, to say the least.

My question is currently I am running a method to check when specific radio buttons are checked and when they are, to output a certain value (10.00, 15.00 or 20.00). But when then the application starts it automatically selects 10.00 and the output values will not change. I have broken this down to the else statement autoselecting 10.00 and is outputting the 10.00 as it has been told to. My issue is when I remove the else statement I just get a 0.00 in the output section.

[Here is an image of the membership form to give you an idea of the prototype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66V8P.png)

Keep in mind I am currently just trying to do the 'Type of Membership' part of the form, I am hoping once I can get passed that then everything else should make a bit more sense. I know there is also a text box in the staff only section, I had that there to see if it would react differently to a normal label which it hasn't.

Here is the code I am currently working with -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Membership_Formv2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PackagePrice();
    }

    public double PackagePrice()
    {
        double BasePrice = 0;

        {

            if (radioButton5.Checked == true)
            {
                BasePrice = 10.00;


            }
            else if (radioButton6.Checked == true)
            {
                BasePrice = 15.00;
                
            }
            else if (radioButton7.Checked == true)
            {
                BasePrice = 20.00;
            }
            else
            {
                radioButton5.Checked = true;
                BasePrice = 10.00;
            };

            label41.Text = BasePrice.ToString("###0.00");

            return BasePrice;
        }


    }

    private void radioButton5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void radioButton10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
}
```

I would really appreciate any help with this.

Thanks

Comment: Neither c# nor VS are auto selecting anything -  your form constructor is executing `PackagePrice()` which selects `radioButton5` if none of the others are.  RadioButtons get their name from their nature of always having one and only one selected.  Used that way you could simply update via those click events.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And yes, that makes sense thank you. How would I go about simply updating them via the click events? Because that is what I had intended with my IF statements. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not really clear what the problem is. If you don't want radioButton5 to be checked than don't write `radioButton5.Checked = true;`

Comment: Okay fair point. I was more using it for if the user does not select anything but I can see the problem in that now. But when I remove this I still have the issue of none of my if statements working..

Comment: PackagePrice() will get executed one time at the beginning of the program. So if you change your selection PackagePrice() will not get executed automatically. You could run PackagePrice() inside your "radioButton{x}_Click(...)" methodes.

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much, something so simple caused so much annoyance haha. Much appreciated, have a good day.